# Many files "missing from working copy" in Release-iphonesimulator

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, warnings

I'm having trouble with a whole bunch of warnings about missing files since upgrading to Swift 3 in Xcode 8.1. I've attached an image with a sample of the errors. There are about 40 of them in total.

All refer to files missing from `MyApp/build/MyApp.build/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/x86-64/...`. None of them are files which I would not have touched or edited.

[image]

I have cleaned and rebuilt, cleaned build folder, deleted all derived data, and a few other things, all with no luck. The app compiles and runs, but has this stack of warnings I can't get rid of.

I also double checked my Release Search Path in Build Settings. Here is what I have it set to:

[image]

These have me stumped. Any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: I faced this warning with some png. I fixed it with a commit. I don't know if it will work in your case since your files are very different but it's worth giving a shot.

Comment: @Eva Sahz, I have tried committing and have used Refresh Status several times, but no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this. It WAS version control related. I had tried committing and resetting status, with no luck. However, when I tried a Pull, it said I had uncommitted changes, even though I had just committed. Therefore, I tried Discard All Changes, and that solved it. Did a clean and build and the warnings are now gone.